# Obtengo este error al intentar ingresar a mi app via localhost en la web: No Default page set up

Tags: laravel-5

no soy experta en programación solo tengo un proyecto de laravel que he intentado configurar en mi pc usando xampp he usado composer y cmd para la configuración. El tema es que cuando ya he finalizado la configuración voy a mi navegador y coloco la ruta donde se encuentra mi proyecto y obtengo este error: No Default page set up ! he buscado en google y lo único que he encontrado es que no tiene esa página creada.

EDIT:
Gracias por la pronta respuesta.
[Aquí dejo el código del controller:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_zI4-c6nt0-xMnNncVE26R5IwwUHUQu7)

P.D. Si estoy entrando al ruta correcta en el servidor. Lo que no tengo es una página que se despliegue, ahí les dejé el código. Lo que me aparece al entrar en el servidor es lo que verán en la última línea del código. ¿Entonces que quiero?
Que me despliegue el dashboard, al entrar a la homepage.

EDIT 2:

### Aquí está el código:

/**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

```
public function index(  Request $request  )
{
    if(CNF_FRONT =='false' && $request->segment(1) =='' ) :
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    endif;  

    if(CNF_MAINTENANCE =='ON') :
        return view('errors.maintenance');
    endif;  

    $page = $request->segment(1);
    if($page !='') :
        $content = \DB::table('tb_pages')->where('alias','=',$page)->where('status','=','enable')->get();
        \DB::table('tb_pages')->where('alias','=',$page)->update(array('views'=> \DB::raw('views+1')));



        if(count($content) >=1)
        {

            $row = $content[0];
            $this->data['pageTitle']    = $row->title;
            $this->data['pageImage']    = ($row->image !='' ? $row->image : CNF_HEADERIMAGE) ;
            $this->data['pageNote']     = $row->note;
            $this->data['pageMetakey']  = ($row->metakey !='' ? $row->metakey : CNF_METAKEY) ;
            $this->data['pageMetadesc'] = ($row->metadesc !='' ? $row->metadesc : CNF_METADESC) ;
            $this->data['homepage']     = $row->default;

            $this->data['breadcrumb'] = 'active';                   

            if($row->access !='')
            {
                $access = json_decode($row->access,true)    ;   
            } else {
                $access = array();
            }   

            // If guest not allowed 
            if($row->allow_guest !=1)
            {   
                $group_id = \Session::get('gid');               
                $isValid =  (isset($access[$group_id]) && $access[$group_id] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );    
                if($isValid ==0)
                {
                    return Redirect::to('')
                        ->with('message', \SiteHelpers::alert('error',\Lang::get('core.note_restric')));                
                }
            }               

            if(file_exists(base_path().'/resources/views/layouts/'.CNF_THEME.'/template/'.$row->filename.'.blade.php') && $row->filename !='')
            {
                $page_template = 'layouts.'.CNF_THEME.'.template.'.$row->filename;
            } else {
                $page_template = 'layouts.'.CNF_THEME.'.template.page';
            }

            $this->data['content'] = \PostHelpers::formatContent($row->note);
            $this->data['filename'] = $row->filename;

        //  echo '<pre>';print_r($this->data);echo '</pre>'; exit;
            if($row->template =='backend')
            {
                $this->data['pageNote'] = 'View';
                 return view($page_template,$this->data);
            } else {

                $this->data['pages'] = $page_template;
                $page = 'layouts.'.CNF_THEME.'.index';
                return view($page,$this->data);
            }               




        } else {
            return Redirect::to('')
                ->with('message', \SiteHelpers::alert('error',\Lang::get('core.note_noexists')));   
        }


    else :

        $sql = \DB::table('tb_pages')->where('default',1)->get();
        if(count($sql)>=1)
        {
            $row = $sql[0];

            $this->data['pageTitle']    =  $row->title;
            $this->data['pageImage']    =  ($row->image !='' ? $row->image : CNF_HEADERIMAGE) ;
            $this->data['pageNote']     =  $row->note;
            $this->data['breadcrumb']   = 'inactive';   
            $this->data['pageMetakey']  =  $row->metakey ;
            $this->data['pageMetadesc'] =  $row->metadesc ;
            $this->data['filename']     =  $row->filename;              
            $this->data['homepage']     =  $row->default;               

            if(file_exists(base_path().'/resources/views/layouts/'.CNF_THEME.'/template/'.$row->filename.'.blade.php') && $row->filename !='')
            {
                $page_template = 'layouts.'.CNF_THEME.'.template.'.$row->filename;
            } else {
                $page_template = 'layouts.'.CNF_THEME.'.template.page';
            }

            $this->data['pages'] = $page_template;
            $this->data['content'] = \PostHelpers::formatContent($row->note);
            $page = 'layouts.'.CNF_THEME.'.index';
            return view($page,$this->data);             

        } else {

            return ' No Default page set up !';
        }

    endif;

}
```

---

Querían código dentro de la pregunta. Ahí lo tienen.

Comment: Sumado a lo que dijo Aprendiz, exactamente a que URL estás queriendo acceder?

Comment: El controller debe estar dentro de la pregunta, los enlaces caducan.

Comment: ¿Algo más? ¿Por qué sigue cerrada?

Answer (score 0):

**Tratare de ver si puedo ayudarte.**

**PRIMERO:** Viendo el codigo que colocaste he visto que el error que reporta es de tipo  personal de tu aplicacion por eso no vas a conseguir ayuda sobre el tema:

Entonces el problema no radica en el acceso a la ruta sino mas bien en consulta de la tabla y un reporte.

Si te fijas lo que esta pasando es que no encuentra el registro o no se comunica con la tabla de la base de datos.

```
 $sql = \DB::table('tb_pages')->where('default',1)->get();
        if(count($sql)>=1)
        {
         } else {

            return ' No Default page set up !';
        }
```

Entonces basandome en esta informacion las Posibles soluciones son:

1) Verifica que se este haciendo bien la conexion con la base de datos en archivo .env que se encuentra en el directorio raiz del proyecto.

2) Verifica la existencia de la base de datos que estas apuntando en el motor MySQL / MariaDB

3) Verifica si tienes tablas en la base de datos, en caso contrario Debes ejecutar la migracion del proyecto: comando artisan migrate.

4) Verifica si tiene datos para poblados para la tablas (tb_pages) en caso de no tener deber verificar si la aplicacion tiene los fakefactory y seeder para poblar contenido en modo desarrollo o pruebas.

5) Verifica si existe por lo menus un campo default con valor 1 en la tabla tb_pages.

NOTA:

El composer es un gestor de paquetes el cual se usa para la Instalacion de Laravel, librerias y dependencias.  no es empleado para configuracion.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias. Estaré verificando estos puntos que mencionas, y veré que tal me va.

Comment: siempre a la orden, acuerdate de calificar la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

¿Ejecutas el siguiente comando de composer en la consola de Windows?:

> php artisan serve

¿cuando lo ejecutas donde te dice que está el servidor?en que puerto?

deberías entrar mediante:

> localhost:8000

Esa es la ruta por defecto.